# Linear search for Strings in Java

Tags: java, arrays, linear-search

I'm working on a code where a user inputs ten strings which is store in an array, and a search key. The code has to run a linear search based on the search key. So far this is what I've got:

```
import java.io.*;
class linstring
{

    String array[] = new String[10];
    String a = new String();
    public void linsearch(String string[], String search)
    {
        string = array;
        search = a;

        int i;
        int flag = 0;
        for(i = 0; i<10; i++)
        {
            if (search.equals(string[i]))
            {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }

        }
        if (flag ==1)
        {
            System.out.println("Word found at position " +(i+1));
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Word not found.");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        linstring obj = new linstring();
        System.out.println("Enter any 10 words.");

        String enter [] = new String[10];
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i<10; i++)
        {

            enter[i] = br.readLine();

        }
        System.out.println("Enter word to be searched.");
        String search1 = br.readLine();
        obj.linsearch(enter, search1);
    }
}
```

No compilation errors and no runtime errors found. However, there is a huge logical error. When I search for an element which IS PRESENT in the array, it says that the search was unsuccessful. How do I solve this?

Comment: Unless this is some homework, I would recommend you forget about the raw-array and use a HashMap/HashSet instead. Faster, less code, less bugs.

Comment: I see. Okay, I'll surely try using HashMap. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove these lines:

```
string = array;
search = a;
```

**Edit:** These two lines set the reference of `string` to an empty String array (`array`) and the reference of `search` to an empty String (`a`). This means that `string` and `search` now have the same content as `array` and `a`, which is empty.

Comment: I realize they do absolutely nothing. I removed them and it works like clockwork now. Thank you! I'm marking this as the answer in 9 minutes.

Comment: @codefoodgirl_99 Yes they **do** something (and this is why your search didn't work).

Comment: Oh. I realize what they did. I removed them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the following line:

```java
string = array;
```

It should be reverse.